# Kivy .exe file not working - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'size'

Tags: python, kivy

I have an issue when I create an .exe of a Kivy application. The application runs perfectly in .py, but when I create an executable, I receive an error - `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'size'`  - in terminal when running the .exe.

The error hints at line 43 of the code which is `Window.size = (1700, 1050)`.

I am aware that this issue has been discussed already here [Kivy Window.size: [WARNING] stderr: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'size'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57021430/kivy-window-size-warning-stderr-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-att), but unfortunately installing dependencies did not solve the issue. I have also tried to install older version of Kivy, but with no success.

Did anyone had similar problem?

Comment: What does `create an executable` mean?

Comment: It means that I create an .exe file of the python script through auto-py-to-exe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'something'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/why-do-i-get-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something)

Answer (score 0):

[auto-py-to-exe](https://github.com/brentvollebregt/auto-py-to-exe) is a GUI for [PyInstaller](https://pypi.org/project/pyinstaller/).

To be able to build exe with PyInstaller follow these instructions:
https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-windows.html

Based on this to create standalone exe you will need to adjust PyInstaller spec file, which is not possible using auto-py-to-exe. My advice is to use pure PyInstaller.

You can follow the steps I described here: [Unable to build kivy image loaded .py file into exe using auto-py-to-exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175996/unable-to-build-kivy-image-loaded-py-file-into-exe-using-auto-py-to-exe/75178588#75178588)

Answer (score -1):

I am also getting the same error. I added a few conditions about initializing the object with default parameters and also added the assets in the directory of the exe file. This worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33650251)